# Arm Cortex G++ I am writing a edma serial driver for a cortex M7+ I am trying to use c++, want to know if it is possible

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cortex-m, dma

I am writing a cortex M7+ edma serial driver. I want to do it in c++ I have it working in c from the examples from the manufacturer. One of the problems I am having a few problems. I know how to call a static C++ function from the interrupt that is not the problem. The problem is that their driver requires that the ciruclar buffer for the edma transfer be located in non cacheable memory.

```
/* allocate ring buffer section. */
AT_NONCACHEABLE_SECTION_INIT(uint8_t _ringBuffer[RX_RING_BUFFER_SIZE]) = {0};
/* Allocate TCD memory poll with ring buffer used. */
AT_NONCACHEABLE_SECTION_ALIGN(static edma_tcd_t _tcdMemoryPoolPtr[1], 
sizeof(edma_tcd_t));
```

Is there a way to do this with class variables, or when I instantiate my class do I need to place the whole class in this area? Or should I just leave the darn thing in C??

Thanks

Comment: You can't place a class variable in a different section. But you can place the whole class there. Or give the class a reference to the buffer or a subclass holding all the noncacheable data.

Comment: You don't have to make everything a class in C++. These variables may be standalone and not be a part of any class. Your class can hold a reference/pointer to them. Or you can make them static class members.

Comment: @where's-my-share. Yes, I know, I was trying to make it a class variable though. I already had it working as a static c variable and just having the class access it. However; then if I want have multiple uarts running the same class, I have to create an array of static variables.

Comment: I recommend reviewing the Linker's command language.  You should have the Linker set up an area in "non-cachable" memory.  The compiler should have a non-standard method for allocating variables in specific regions (as named by the linker).  The IAR compiler uses the `@` for this purpose.